# How do I build a multiple-nested list in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, list-view

Let's say I have a SharePoint list that looks like this:

```
Country         Region             State           City           Customer
USA             Northwest          Washington      Seattle        Jims Coffee
USA             Southeast          Florida         Orlando        Publix Markets
USA             Southwest          Arizona         Tempe          Mesa Airways
USA             Northwest          Oregon          Portland       Lee University
USA             Southeast          Florida         Tampa          Port Authority
```

I'm interested in having collapsible sections of a page that users can expand and collapse at the Country, Region, State, and City level.

Can anyone explain to me how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify view and use grouping feature.

Open list settings and click on the view. In the view settings page scroll and expand Group. Select country from the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `Group By` on any of the two fields. By default SharePoint allows you to Group By only by two columns under the Modify view section.